# How to test a class that contains no methods

Tags: apex, unit-test, map, code-coverage, getter

I have a class that only contains one map.

```
public with sharing class testController {
    public Map<String, User[]> mapName {get {.....return value;} set;}
}
```

I am unable to instantiate the class or call the method because it is not actually a method. How would I start testing something like this? Is there any documentation on testing with no methods to test? I can't find any documentation on something like this.

I have tried to manually create a user list, query a user list, instantiate the testController, and a few other variations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still test it, because classes that have no defined constructors still have a *default constructor*. So, your unit test would look like this:

```
@isTest static void test() {
    testController c = new testController();
    System.assertNotEquals(null, c.mapName);
}
```

Comment: ah great. I wasn't calling the assertNotEquals correctly. thank you!

Comment: @Olivia Glad I could help! Sometimes its the little things we miss.

Comment: how do i test a map on a trigger? @sfdcfox